# If $\int f^*(x)g(x) dx$ is the scalar product in the vector space of $L^2$, what is $f(x)g(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For two functions $v=f(x)$, $w=g(x)$ from the vector space $L^2$, the scalar product $v^Tw$ is defined to be

$\int f^*(x)g(x) dx$.

However, I can also just multiply one function with another, $f(x)\cdot g(x)$. What is the corresponding algebraic operation?

Comment: The pointwise product $fg$ does not generally belong to $L^2$ if $f, g\in L^2$. So that operation is not even well-defined. Anyway, it would correspond to the so-called Hadamard product of two vectors; if $v=(v_1,\ldots, v_n), w=(w_1, \ldots, w_n)$ then $v\circ w:=(v_1w_1, \ldots, v_nw_n)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Answer (score -1):

It's not a vector space operation, because in a vector space $V$ the only $V \times V \to V$ operation is the addition.

Comment: @AlphaOmega what do you mean by corresponding algebraic operation? The multiplication of functions (functions between $2$ fields at least) is defined with the multiplication on the field: $(fg)(x):=f(x)g(x)$

Comment: Would the downvoter mind explain the reason of the downvote?

Comment: $f(x)$ is a vector. $g(x)$ is a vector. I can do the operation $f(x)g(x)$ by either saying that I am taking the product of two functions, or that I am performing a specific operations with these two vectors (which, again, leaves me with a member of the original vector space). So what kind of operation am I performing here?

Comment: @AlphaOmega $f$ and $g$ are the vectors, not $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. The multiplication of functions is not an operation "given by" the vector space itself. And there is nothing special in the operation you mentioned - I can come up with a lot of different ones.

Comment: what's the difference between $f$ and $f(x)$?

Comment: @AlphaOmega From a set theoretical point of view a function $f: A \to B$ is an element of $A\times B$. On the other hand, $f(x)$ is just one element in $B$.

Comment: @AlphaOmega and the product of 2 $L^2$ functions is not in $L^2$ in general, as Giuseppe said. The same goes for the derivative of an $L^2$ function.

Comment: thank you. So, for $f: A\rightarrow B$, then $f \in A\times B$? Like in, $f(x) =x \Rightarrow f\in \mathbb{R}^2$? Why is that?

Comment: @AlphaOmega Because that's a way to define a function. There are other ways as well, but $f$ is not the same as $f(x)$. Of course, we can identify $f$ with $f(x)$, when it can't cause confusion. But I think it's just a small detail here.

Comment: I see, could you give me an instructive example? Say, $f(x) = x \Rightarrow f \in \mathbb{R}^2$, so I should be able to identify $f$ with some vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$, like $(2,3)$ (Otherwise it wouldn't be in $\mathbb{R}^2$). I don't really see why this is true. Or could you point me somewhere where I can read more about it?

Comment: @AlphaOmega  Sorry, I used the wrong word. $f: A \to B$ is not an element of $A \times B$, but a subset. In your example, $f=\{(x,y)|x,y \in \mathbb{R} \land x=y\}$.